# Parsing a CSV string into a 2d object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to figure out how to parse a csv string into an object that will allow me to go to a customers name in the first object and then being able to access the said customers information in a sub array based off of which name.

```
csvString = "roll R coaster,0124454,20.21\n
```

I know that the .split() function will split the string based off a delimiter and place it in an array. If I use "\n" as my first delimiter, 5 array elements are created for each client followed by their respective information.

```
array[0] = "roll R coaster,0124454,20.21"
```

Comment: You could make use of the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and parse each row with split

Answer (score 1):

I think this code does pretty much what you need.

```js
csvString = "roll R coaster,0124454,20.21\n  Sammy Smocks,000006,(20.20)\n maxwell BLANCO  ,002125,(15),\n Will   Monsters,003576,6.9,15\n Trank   Burger,103529,9.56,5";


const objects = csvString.split('\n ')
  .map(x => {
    const [name, TransactionNumber, TrAm] = x.split(',');
    TransactionAmount = TrAm[0] === '(' ? +TrAm.slice(1, -1) : +TrAm;
    
    FullName = name
     .replace(/^\s{2,}/g, ' ')
      .replace(/\s{3}/g, '  ')
      .replace(/\s{2}$/g, ' ');
            
    const [FirstName, MiddleName, LastName] = FullName.split(' ');
    
    return {
      FirstName, 
      MiddleName, 
      LastName, 
      TransactionNumber,
      TransactionAmount
    }
  });

console.log(objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

So we take in the csv as a string, split it on the '\n' to get each row. We then split the row using regex, you suggest by your wanted object properties that this is a predictable input per-row so we take that and pop it into a json object and return it. You can then access it via myData[i]).firstName. Woith a minor change you could, if you wanted, give each row an identified such as the transaction number, so myData["000006"].lastName would return 'Smocks'.

```
let csvString = "roll R coaster,0124454,20.21\n  Sammy Smocks,000006,(20.20)\n maxwell BLANCO  ,002125,(15),\n Will Monsters,003576,6.9,15\n Trank   Burger,103529,9.56,5";  
let myData = [];

csvString.split('\n').forEach((row) => {
  let rowData = row.match(/(\w+) *(\w*) *(\w*),(.+),(.+)/i);
  myData.push({
    firstname: rowData[1],
    middleName: rowData[3] ? rowData[2] : "",
    lastName: rowData[3] ? rowData[3] : rowData[2],
    transactionNumber: rowData[4],
    transactionAmount: rowData[5]
  });
});
console.log(myData);
```

Output:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0:{firstname: "roll", middleName: "R", lastName: "coaster", transactionNumber: "0124454", transactionAmount: "20.21"}
  1:{firstname: "Sammy", middleName: "", lastName: "Smocks", transactionNumber: "000006", transactionAmount: "(20.20)"}
  2:{firstname: "maxwell", middleName: "", lastName: "BLANCO", transactionNumber: "002125", transactionAmount: "(15),"}
  3:{firstname: "Will", middleName: "", lastName: "Monsters", transactionNumber: "003576,6.9", transactionAmount: "15"}
  4:{firstname: "Trank", middleName: "", lastName: "Burger", transactionNumber: "103529,9.56", transactionAmount: "5"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected , you can use below option of using array map() method twice - one for FirstName,MiddleName, LastName and other for remaining comma separated values - TransactionNumber, TransactionAmount

```
  var csv = "roll R coaster,0124454,20.21".split(",");
  var keys = [["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName"], "TransactionNumber","TransactionAmount"]
  var Obj ={}

  csv.map((val, i)=>{
    if(i == 0){
      val.split(" ").map((v,idx)=>{
          Obj[keys[0][idx]] = v.toUpperCase()
      }) 
    }else{
      Obj[keys[i]] = val
    }

  })
  console.log(Obj)
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aqaGQN?editors=1010